# HTML - Extra Space in table... debug

Tags: html, css

look at this image

[image]

see the white are below the grey... **its not supposed to be there** find me a cure

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="30">
<tr>
    <td>
    <div class="mainmenu">
    <ul>
          <li class="li_nc"><a href="/" target="_self" >HOME</a></li>
          <li class="li_hc"><a href="#"  >PROGRAMS</a><ul class="ul_ch">
             <li class="li_hc"><a href="#"  >Engineering</a><ul class="ul_ch">
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >BEE ( Electronics 4 Years )</a></li>
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >BEE ( Tele Comm. 4 Years )</a></li>
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >BSE ( Software 4 Years )</a></li>
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >BCE (Computer 4 Years)</a></li>
             </ul></li>
             <li class="li_hc"><a href="#"  >Management Sciences</a><ul class="ul_ch">
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >BBA ( Years )</a></li>
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >MBA ( 3 Years )</a></li>
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >MBA ( 2 1/2 Years )</a></li>
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >MBA ( 1 1/2 Years )</a></li>
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >MBA ( Weekend )</a></li>
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >MBA ( Pharma )</a></li>
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Ph.D Management</a></li>
             </ul></li>
             <li class="li_hc"><a href="#"  >Earth & Environmental Sciences</a><ul class="ul_ch">
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >BS ( Geology\Geophysics )</a></li>
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >MS  ( Geology\Geophysics )</a></li>
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >MS ( Environmental Policy & Management )</a></li>
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >MS & Ph.D ( Environmental )</a></li>
             </ul></li>
             <li class="li_hc"><a href="#"  >Professional Psychology</a><ul class="ul_ch">
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >BS ( 4 Years )</a></li>
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >PMD ( 1 Year )</a></li>
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >M. Phil ( 1-2 Years )</a></li>
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Ph.D ( 2-3 Years )</a></li>
             </ul></li>
             <li class="li_hc"><a href="#"  >Marine & Maritime Sciences</a><ul class="ul_ch">
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >MBA ( 1-5 Years )</a></li>
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >MBA ( Maritime 2-5 Years )</a></li>
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >MBA ( Maritime 3 Years )</a></li>
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >MSC ( Geophysics 2 Years )</a></li>
             </ul></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Graduate & Applie Sciences</a></li>
             <li class="li_hc"><a href="#"  >Humanities & Social Sciences</a><ul class="ul_ch">
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >BSS ( 4 Years )</a></li>
             </ul></li>
             <li class="li_hc"><a href="#"  >Medical & Dental Sciences</a><ul class="ul_ch">
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >MBBS ( 5 Years )</a></li>
             </ul></li>
             <li class="li_hc"><a href="#"  >Legal Studies</a><ul class="ul_ch">
                <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >LLB ( 5 Years )</a></li>
             </ul></li>
          </ul></li>
          <li class="li_hc"><a href="#"  >ADMISSIONS</a><ul class="ul_ch">
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >General Info</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Eligibility</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Admissions Procedure</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Freshmen Orientation</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >How To Apply ?</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Prospectus</a></li>
          </ul></li>
          <li class="li_hc"><a href="#"  >ACADEMICS</a><ul class="ul_ch">
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Semester System</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Examination System</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Course\Syllabus</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Faculty Evaluation</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Rules & Regulations</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Degree Recognition</a></li>
          </ul></li>
          <li class="li_hc"><a href="#"  >FACILITIES</a><ul class="ul_ch">
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Student Support Facilities</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Laboratories</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Computer Laboratories</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Audio & Visual Facilities</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Medical Services</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Security Services</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Sports Facilities</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Study & Excursion Trips</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Cafeterias & Dinning</a></li>
          </ul></li>
          <li class="li_hc"><a href="#"  >FACULTY</a><ul class="ul_ch">
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Islamabad Campus</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Karachi Campus</a></li>
          </ul></li>
          <li class="li_hc"><a href="#"  >ABOUT</a><ul class="ul_ch">
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >History</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Board Of Governers</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Constituent Units</a></li>
             <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >Affiliated Units</a></li>
          </ul></li>
          <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >CONTACT US</a></li>
          <li class="li_nc"><a href="#"  >VIRTUAL TOUR</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Following is the CSS for this

```
/* pull-down mainmenu css */
.mainmenu{
    float  : left;
    width  : 100%;
    height : 30;
    padding: 0;

    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
    border-width:0;

}
.mainmenu ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1;
    color:#e0e0e0;
    background: #474747;
    padding: 0;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

.mainmenu a, .mainmenu a:visited 
{
    display: block;
    font-family:calibri;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:underline;
    color: #e0e0e0;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1em 1em;
}

.mainmenu ul ul a{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.mainmenu ul a{
    width:1%;
}


.mainmenu li  {
    float: left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.mainmenu ul li 
{
 float:left; position:relative;  
}

.mainmenu ul li a 
{
 white-space:nowrap;
}

.mainmenu li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    height: auto;
    width:15em; 

    background: #474747;
    font-weight: normal;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin: 0;
}

.mainmenu li li {
    width:15em ;
}

.mainmenu li li a{
    width:13em ;
}

.mainmenu li ul  {
    margin: 0;
}
.mainmenu li ul ul {
    margin: -2.8em 0 0 13.5em;
}
.ul_ch, 
.mainmenu li:hover ul ul,
.mainmenu li li:hover ul ul,
.mainmenu li li li:hover ul ul,
.mainmenu li li li li:hover ul ul,
.mainmenu li li li li li:hover ul ul
{
    left: -999em;
}
.mainmenu li:hover ul,
.mainmenu li li:hover ul,
.mainmenu li li li:hover ul,
.mainmenu li li li li:hover ul,
.mainmenu li li li li li:hover ul
{
    left: auto;
}
.mainmenu li:hover>ul.ul_ch   
{
    left: auto;
}

.mainmenu li:hover{
    background: #0552a7;
}

.mainmenu li:hover a,.mainmenu li:hover a:visited,.mainmenu li:hover a:hover,.mainmenu li a:hover{
    color:#e0e0e0;
}
.mainmenu li:hover li a, .mainmenu li li:hover li a, 
.mainmenu li li li:hover li a, .mainmenu li li li li:hover li a,
.mainmenu li:hover li a:visited, .mainmenu li li:hover li a:visited, 
.mainmenu li li li:hover li a:visited, .mainmenu li li li li:hover li a:visited
{
    color:#e0e0e0;
}
.mainmenu li li:hover, .mainmenu li li li:hover, 
.mainmenu li li li li:hover , .mainmenu li li li li li:hover , .mainmenu li li li li li li:hover 
{
    background: #0552a7;
    z-index:9999;
}
.mainmenu li li:hover a,.mainmenu li li li:hover a, 
.mainmenu li li li li:hover a, .mainmenu li li li li li:hover a
{
    color: #e0e0e0; 
}

.mainmenu ul ul a, .mainmenu ul ul a:visited,
.mainmenu li li a, .mainmenu li li a:visited
{
    color: #e0e0e0;
}
.mainmenu ul ul a:hover,
.mainmenu li:hover li:hover a,.mainmenu li:hover li:hover a:visited ,
.mainmenu li:hover li:hover li:hover a,.mainmenu li:hover li:hover li:hover a:visited,
.mainmenu li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover a,.mainmenu li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover a:visited ,
.mainmenu li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover a,.mainmenu li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover a:visited,
.mainmenu li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover a,.mainmenu li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover a:visited{
    color: #e0e0e0;
}
.mainmenu li:hover li:hover li a,.mainmenu li:hover li:hover li a:visited ,
.mainmenu li:hover li:hover li:hover li a,.mainmenu li:hover li:hover li:hover li a:visited,
.mainmenu li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li a,.mainmenu li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li a:visited,
.mainmenu li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li a,.mainmenu li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li a:visited{
    color: #e0e0e0;
}


/* end of mainmenu css */
```

this is a CSS Menu which i generated from a tool called **CSS Menu Generator**... i have posted the complete CSS and HTML please solve

NOTE: the solution must not take away the formatting of the menu that you see in the image above

Comment: your table height is set to 30, any reason?

Comment: I' can't see the image, but I have an idea what's wrong. Verify that the `<ul>` element has no padding, margins, or height specifications causing the extra white space.

Comment: thats because it is part of my page and desugn says so but the image you are seeing if its height 40 appx... but that is not the prob

Comment: Please post a bigger chunck of html.  We can't see what's below your gray rectangle.  Obviously it'll be white below there because that's where the content stops.  Which part is grey? Is it the div, the ul, the td, the table?  We need more code.

Comment: i have posted code as answer to my own question please see below

Comment: dude, delete your answers and edit your question, everything here is super messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is dificult to say what is going on w/o ability to inspect stuff with Firebug, but looking and the code you sent:

```
.mainmenu ul {
    ..snip..
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    ..snip..
}
```

This rule is applying 1em margin on the bottom, change it to: `margin:0` and you should be fine.

**PLEASE** next time instead of adding your answers with more information about your problem just modify your question. This is not a forum!

Comment: @Rochal: Check your reputation to measure my appreciation

Comment: @Rochal: 1997 to 2211 ... i think i earned you Moratrboard badge today

Comment: @Moon . - ok.. thanks.. I appreciate that but don't EVER do it again. Reputation is used to measure the expertise of our answers and by faking (voting up) random questions you are not helping anyone....

Comment: @Rochal: could you help me with this code.. it is a CSS Menu code...
now i want to add seperators... i have a 1x35 image to use as seperator
i know CSS is going to be 
background : #333333 url("images/hover.gif") bottom right no-repeat;
but i can't figure out where to put it... its a tool generated code and i fail to understand it

Comment: @Moon, you should seriously follow the rules. If you have new question - just ask it as new post, someone will help out. BTW - all the fake reputation you gave me was automatically taken back. So for the future - play by the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, insert the closing `</li>`.

Secondly, IE especially has a problem with "hidden" white space; so put things on one line to see if that solves the problem and then tab again as necessary:

```
<table border="01" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="30">
<tr>
    <td>
    <div class="mainmenu">
        <ul><li><!-- A LOT OF HTML CODE HERE--><!-- AFTER A LOT OF HTML CODE HERE--></li></ul>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: ..also, you have set the border on the table to 1, and the height of that table to 30. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: I believe missing `<li>` this is just a copy&paste issue.